# Javascript variable with html add class to color the text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a variable that contains html code.

```
var link = "<li><a href="#"></a></li>";
```

I want to color my element a which is repeat n times. So I did : 
`document.getElementsByTagName("a").addClass("selected")`

And in my css I defined

```
.selected{ color: red; }
```

But it seems to not work. Nothing changed in the html.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `addClass()` is not a native dom method. Please open your browser console and look at errors thrown. Big clues there!

Comment: Hint: Look at the syntax... You are terminating the string prematurely. You should use:  `var link = "<li><a href='#'></a></li>";`

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` gives you a collection of DOM elements (even if it's a collection of one) so you would need to iterate through the collection and apply the class to each item. Also, `addClass()` is a jQuery method, the vanilla JS way is to use `.classList()` (e.g. `elem.classList.add('selected')`).

Comment: Aaand... If you use ByTagName you must specify *which* tag in the DOM collection. So it should be: `document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addClass("selected");` for the first tag, `[1]` for the second, `[2]` for the third...

Comment: Are the contents of `link` event rendered in the document...???

Comment: `getElementsByTagName( 'a' )` will return **all** `<a>` on the page! Not just the ones in a certain group of `<li>`. Use `querySelectorAll()` with a more specific selector.

Comment: Thanks but nothing worked. :( Maybe I should give you more context. In fact each of my li is fill with the values collected in my array. I have an array [{a:"banana", b:"split"}, {a:"orange", b:"apple"} ...]  The li are filled with only the a values. <li><a Href..>banana</a></li> <li><a Href..>orange</a></li>. I want to color only the li with a certain condition. So I did:  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){ if(x == true){this.color.style = "red"} }

Comment: the li that fill the condition